# Repo method not returning data to controller (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have repo method to get data from db

Here is repo method

```
 public List<PatientMasterDataViewModel> GetPatientData(string name)
    {
        using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            List<PatientMasterDataViewModel> patientdata = new List<PatientMasterDataViewModel>();
            var items = ctx.Patients.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();
            for (int i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                patientdata.Add(new PatientMasterDataViewModel
                {
                    Id = items[i].Id,
                    Name = items[i].Name,
                    Birthday = items[i].Date_of_Birthday
                });
            }

            return patientdata;
        }
    }
```

after this I need to get this data in controller method

Here is controller method

```
public JsonResult PatientMasterDataInfo(string name)
    {
        var masterdatainfo = _repository.GetPatientData(name);
        return Json(masterdatainfo.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In Repo in `items` I have data

Here is screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH58E.png)

But for some reasons it not adding to patientdata and as result in controller I have null.

Where is my trouble?

Comment: Why are you converting the results to an array `.ToArray()`? Just return them as is (`List<T>`). Also you have only 1 item in your screenshot, but your loop is starting from the second item `int i = 1`, so that one item is not selected in the loop. If you have more items it will work and skip the first item. If that's not what you want, change the loop to start from the first item `int i = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have loop started from 1. Please start it from 0 index.

```
public List<PatientMasterDataViewModel> GetPatientData(string name)
{
    using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        List<PatientMasterDataViewModel> patientdata = new List<PatientMasterDataViewModel>();
        var items = ctx.Patients.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            patientdata.Add(new PatientMasterDataViewModel
            {
                Id = items[i].Id,
                Name = items[i].Name,
                Birthday = items[i].Date_of_Birthday
            });
        }

        return patientdata;
    }
}
```

Comment: O h , yeah, I cannot see this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should not be `null` as per your code what you have but i see one issue in your code which is your loop is string from 1 not 0 so change it to :

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
}
```